# Convergence analysis of gradient descent method

Tags: convex-optimization, subgradient

From the following:

> Convex Optimization (S. Boyd)   p.467

Content:

> We will see that the gradient method does in fact require a large
>   number of iterations when the Hessian of $f$, near $x^⋆$, has a large
>   condition number. Conversely, when the sublevel sets of $f$ are
>   relatively isotropic, so that the condition number bound $M/m$ can be
>   chosen to be relatively small, the bound (9.18) shows that convergence
>   is rapid, since c is small, or at least not too close to one.

My question is:
What does "**sublevel sets of $f$ are relative isotropic**" means?

Does it mean, for example, a diagonal matrix whose diagonal elements are uniformly distributed?

(I know the definition of sublevel sets and the meaning of isotropic, but have no idea what does the combination of them here mean)

Comment: I have corrected the quoted text. I think the author is basically saying that the level sets are roughly the same size in all directions; that is, they are roughly hyperspherical. For a differentiable function, this means that ratio of the largest eigenvalue and the smallest eigenvalue of the Hessian is always small.

Comment: What does "the same size in all direction" mean? Does the size mean $l_2$ norm of $x \in$ sublevel set?   Besides, $f(x) = x^2, x \in R^2$, for example, in this case, is the sublevel sets of $f(x)$ 'isotropic'? (because the equal-level tour are circles)

Comment: That is basically it, yes.